# php - Undefined offset

Tags: php

How can I fix this undefined offset error.

I get: `Undefined offset 0 - 44, on line 234.`

Line `234` looks like this:

```
$mysql['invo_mysql_where'] .= ( $x > 0 ? " OR " : '' )."`id` = {$mysql['inactive'][$x]}";
```

The entire part of the code, looks like this:

```
shuffle($mysql['inactive']);
        for($x = 0, $l = $mysql['inactive_amount']; $x < $l; $x++){
            $mysql['invo_mysql_where'] .= ( $x > 0 ? " OR " : '' )."`id` = {$mysql['inactive'][$x]}";
        }
```

`$mysql_inactive`:

```
$mysql['inactive'] = array();
        if($ile == 10){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(0, 1);
        } else if($ile == 20){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(0, 2);
        } else if($ile == 30){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(0, 3);
        } else if($ile == 40){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(0, 4);
        } else if($ile == 50){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(0, 4);
        } else if($ile == 60){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(1, 3);
        } else if($ile == 70){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(2, 3);
        } else if($ile == 80){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(3, 4);
        } else if($ile == 90){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(4, 4);

        } else if($ile == 100){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(5, 5);
        } else if($ile == 200){
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(6, 5);
        } else {
            $mysql['inactive_amount'] = mt_rand(20, 50);
        }
        $mysql['invo_mysql_where'] = '';
```

Comment: What is `$mysql['inactive']`? Looks like it's not an array, or its empty.

Comment: Check my question again; I've updated it and added $mysql['inactive'];

Comment: It's a blank array yet you try to access indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you define `$mysql['inactive']` as an empty array here:

```
$mysql['inactive'] = array();
```

Then never add elements to it. Later, you try to use it as a populated array here:

```
$mysql['inactive'][$x]
```

The error occurs because no indexes are defined for the `$mysql['inactive']` array. In order to fix this, you'll need to populate it with some data.